# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/57054 (has extras) }}

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an Image splitting method for a jigsaw puzzle game. Beside the default image the app can pick and split an image from the gallery. I get this error after choosing an image from the gallery and the app force close. Here are my code:

```
ImageView image;
Uri selectedImage;
private final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
int chunkNumbers = 16;
ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages;
Button[] buttons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImgPicker);
choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImageFromGallery();
        }
    });
}

void pickImageFromGallery() {

    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode!=Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //  takenPictureData = handleResultFromChooser(data);
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    splitImage(image, chunkNumbers);

                /*if(selectedImage!=null) {
                    try {
                        InputStream picturePath = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(picturePath);



                        // Function of split the image(divide the image into pieces)
                        splitImage(image, chunkNumbers);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                }
                    //  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                break;
        }
    }
    }
private void splitImage(ImageView image, int chunkNumbers) {

    //For the number of rows and columns of the grid to be displayed
    int rows,cols;

    //For height and width of the small image chunks
    int chunkHeight,chunkWidth;

    //To store all the small image chunks in bitmap format in this list
    chunkedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunkNumbers);

    //Getting the scaled bitmap of the source image
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);

    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/cols;


    //xCoord and yCoord are the pixel positions of the image chunks
    int yCoord = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){
            chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }

    BitmapDrawable[] bmd = (BitmapDrawable[]) chunkedImages.toArray();

    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        buttons[i].setBackgroundDrawable(bmd[i]);
    }

}
```

The error is on line

```
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Can anyone help with the above code? Already tried adding condition like `if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)` or `if (data != null)` but still no result. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/57054 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.duc.puzzledemo/com.example.duc.puzzledemo.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3433)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.duc.puzzledemo.Game.onActivityResult(Game.java:350)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5515)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3429)
```

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I changed my code to :

```
try {
                            InputStream picturePath = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(picturePath);


image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                            // Function of split the image(divide the image into pieces)
                            splitImage(image, chunkNumbers);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
```

But the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, not the least of which is that you asked a question about a crash without providing a full stack trace.

What is probably causing your crash is your invalid code trying to derive `picturePath`. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Treat the `Uri` the same way that you would a URL to a Web server.

Beyond that, you are doing I/O (reading in the image) and significant processing of that image (decoding it) on the main application thread, which freezes your UI while that work is being done.

There are [many image loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Universal Image Loader and Picasso. Most, if not all, of them can take your `Uri` and asychronously load the bitmap into your `ImageView`.

Comment: So what is your suggestion?

Comment: @user3417256: Use one of the image-loading libraries, to load the contents of your `Uri` into the `ImageView` asynchronously. You also have not initialized `image` AFAICT, which is probably the source of the `NullPointerException`.