# TransactionTooLargeException occure on switching new activity

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm developing image capture app in which after capturing image if you do not want to save image, press back button [ onBackPress i launch new activity i.e BottomNavigationActivity] it should switch to home activity (like normal camera app doing).

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BottomNavigationActivity.class));
    }
```

But when i press back button TransactionTooLargeException occur and then app crash. i don't know why this happen even i am not transferring any huge amount of data like arrayList etc. help me to solve this problem
thanks in advance.

**CameraFragment.java** [here i capture the image]

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback
{

    public static final String TAG = CameraFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String CAMERA_ID_KEY = "camera_id";
    public static final String CAMERA_FLASH_KEY = "flash_mode";
    public static final String IMAGE_INFO = "image_info";

    private static final int PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 640;

    private int mCameraID;
    private String mFlashMode;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SquareCameraPreview mPreviewView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private boolean mIsSafeToTakePhoto = false;

    private ImageParameters mImageParameters;

    private CameraOrientationListener mOrientationListener;

    ImageView iv_camera_close;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new CameraFragment();
    }

    public CameraFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mOrientationListener = new CameraOrientationListener(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore your state here because a double rotation with this fragment
        // in the backstack will cause improper state restoration
        // onCreate() -> onSavedInstanceState() instead of going through onCreateView()
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
            mFlashMode = CameraSettingPreferences.getCameraFlashMode(getActivity());
            mImageParameters = new ImageParameters();
        }
        else
        {
            mCameraID = savedInstanceState.getInt(CAMERA_ID_KEY);
            mFlashMode = savedInstanceState.getString(CAMERA_FLASH_KEY);
            mImageParameters = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(IMAGE_INFO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.squarecamera__fragment_camera, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mOrientationListener.enable();

        mPreviewView = (SquareCameraPreview) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_view);
        mPreviewView.getHolder().addCallback(CameraFragment.this);

        final View topCoverView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover_top_view);
        final View btnCoverView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover_bottom_view);
                iv_camera_close = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_camera_close);

                iv_camera_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), BottomNavigationActivity.class));
                    }
                });

        mImageParameters.mIsPortrait =
                getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            ViewTreeObserver observer = mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    mImageParameters.mPreviewWidth = mPreviewView.getWidth();
                    mImageParameters.mPreviewHeight = mPreviewView.getHeight();

                    mImageParameters.mCoverWidth = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight
                            = mImageParameters.calculateCoverWidthHeight();

//                    Log.d(TAG, "parameters: " + mImageParameters.getStringValues());
//                    Log.d(TAG, "cover height " + topCoverView.getHeight());
                    resizeTopAndBtmCover(topCoverView, btnCoverView);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mPreviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (mImageParameters.isPortrait()) {
                topCoverView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight;
                btnCoverView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageParameters.mCoverHeight;
            } else {
                topCoverView.getLayoutParams().width = mImageParameters.mCoverWidth;
                btnCoverView.getLayoutParams().width = mImageParameters.mCoverWidth;
            }
        }

        final ImageView swapCameraBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
        swapCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCameraID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
                } else {
                    mCameraID = getFrontCameraID();
                }
                restartPreview();
            }
        });

        final View changeCameraFlashModeBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.flash);
        changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON;
                } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
                } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
                    mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
                }

                setupFlashMode();
                setupCamera();
            }
        });
        setupFlashMode();

        final ImageView takePhotoBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.capture_image_button);
        takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupFlashMode() {
        View view = getView();
        if (view == null) return;

        final TextView autoFlashIcon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auto_flash_icon);
        if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO.equalsIgnoreCase(mFlashMode)) {
            autoFlashIcon.setText("Auto");
        } else if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON.equalsIgnoreCase(mFlashMode)) {
            autoFlashIcon.setText("On");
        }  else if (Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF.equalsIgnoreCase(mFlashMode)) {
            autoFlashIcon.setText("Off");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putInt(CAMERA_ID_KEY, mCameraID);
        outState.putString(CAMERA_FLASH_KEY, mFlashMode);
        outState.putParcelable(IMAGE_INFO, mImageParameters);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void resizeTopAndBtmCover( final View topCover, final View bottomCover) {
        ResizeAnimation resizeTopAnimation
                = new ResizeAnimation(topCover, mImageParameters);
        resizeTopAnimation.setDuration(800);
        resizeTopAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        topCover.startAnimation(resizeTopAnimation);

        ResizeAnimation resizeBtmAnimation
                = new ResizeAnimation(bottomCover, mImageParameters);
        resizeBtmAnimation.setDuration(800);
        resizeBtmAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        bottomCover.startAnimation(resizeBtmAnimation);
    }

    private void getCamera(int cameraID) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraID);
            mPreviewView.setCamera(mCamera);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't open camera with id " + cameraID);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restart the camera preview
     */
    private void restartPreview() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            stopCameraPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        getCamera(mCameraID);
        startCameraPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Start the camera preview
     */
    private void startCameraPreview() {
        determineDisplayOrientation();
        setupCamera();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
            setCameraFocusReady(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't start camera preview due to IOException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop the camera preview
     */
    private void stopCameraPreview() {
        setSafeToTakePhoto(false);
        setCameraFocusReady(false);

        // Nulls out callbacks, stops face detection
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewView.setCamera(null);
    }

    private void setSafeToTakePhoto(final boolean isSafeToTakePhoto) {
        mIsSafeToTakePhoto = isSafeToTakePhoto;
    }

    private void setCameraFocusReady(final boolean isFocusReady) {
        if (this.mPreviewView != null) {
            mPreviewView.setIsFocusReady(isFocusReady);
        }
    }


    private void determineDisplayOrientation() {
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraID, cameraInfo);

        // Clockwise rotation needed to align the window display to the natural position
        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;

        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: {
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: {
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: {
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            }
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: {
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }
        }

        int displayOrientation;

        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // Orientation is angle of rotation when facing the camera for
            // the camera image to match the natural orientation of the device
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            displayOrientation = (360 - displayOrientation) % 360;
        } else {
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        mImageParameters.mDisplayOrientation = displayOrientation;
        mImageParameters.mLayoutOrientation = degrees;

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mImageParameters.mDisplayOrientation);
    }


    private void setupCamera() {
        // Never keep a global parameters
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        Size bestPreviewSize = determineBestPreviewSize(parameters);
        Size bestPictureSize = determineBestPictureSize(parameters);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.width, bestPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(bestPictureSize.width, bestPictureSize.height);


        // Set continuous picture focus, if it's supported
        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }

        final View changeCameraFlashModeBtn = getView().findViewById(R.id.flash);
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(mFlashMode)) {
            parameters.setFlashMode(mFlashMode);
            changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            changeCameraFlashModeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    private Size determineBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        return determineBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
    }

    private Size determineBestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        return determineBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
    }

    private Size determineBestSize(List<Size> sizes, int widthThreshold) {
        Size bestSize = null;
        Size size;
        int numOfSizes = sizes.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSizes; i++) {
            size = sizes.get(i);
            boolean isDesireRatio = (size.width / 4) == (size.height / 3);
            boolean isBetterSize = (bestSize == null) || size.width > bestSize.width;

            if (isDesireRatio && isBetterSize) {
                bestSize = size;
            }
        }

        if (bestSize == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cannot find the best camera size");
            return sizes.get(sizes.size() - 1);
        }

        return bestSize;
    }

    private int getFrontCameraID() {
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
            return CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        }

        return getBackCameraID();
    }

    private int getBackCameraID() {
        return CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    }

    private void takePicture() {

        if (mIsSafeToTakePhoto) {
            setSafeToTakePhoto(false);

            mOrientationListener.rememberOrientation();
            Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = null;
            Camera.PictureCallback raw = null;    
            // postView callback occurs when a scaled, fully processed
            // postView image is available.
            Camera.PictureCallback postView = null;
            mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, raw, postView, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mCamera == null) {
            restartPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mOrientationListener.disable();

        // stop the preview
        if (mCamera != null) {
            stopCameraPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        CameraSettingPreferences.saveCameraFlashMode(getActivity(), mFlashMode);

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = holder;

        getCamera(mCameraID);
        startCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The surface is destroyed with the visibility of the SurfaceView is set to View.Invisible
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A picture has been taken
     * @param data
     * @param camera
     */
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        int rotation = getPhotoRotation();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(
                        R.id.fragment_container,
                        EditSavePhotoFragment.newInstance(data, rotation, mImageParameters.createCopy()),
                        EditSavePhotoFragment.TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
    }

    private int getPhotoRotation() {
        int rotation;
        int orientation = mOrientationListener.getRememberedNormalOrientation();
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraID, info);

        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
        } else {
            rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
        }

        return rotation;
    }

    /**
     * When orientation changes, onOrientationChanged(int) of the listener will be called
     */
    private static class CameraOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {

        private int mCurrentNormalizedOrientation;
        private int mRememberedNormalOrientation;

        public CameraOrientationListener(Context context) {
            super(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if (orientation != ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                mCurrentNormalizedOrientation = normalize(orientation);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param degrees Amount of clockwise rotation from the device's natural position
         * @return Normalized degrees to just 0, 90, 180, 270
         */
        private int normalize(int degrees) {
            if (degrees > 315 || degrees <= 45) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (degrees > 45 && degrees <= 135) {
                return 90;
            }

            if (degrees > 135 && degrees <= 225) {
                return 180;
            }

            if (degrees > 225 && degrees <= 315) {
                return 270;
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("The physics as we know them are no more. Watch out for anomalies.");
        }

        public void rememberOrientation() {
            mRememberedNormalOrientation = mCurrentNormalizedOrientation;
        }

        public int getRememberedNormalOrientation() {
            rememberOrientation();
            return mRememberedNormalOrientation;
        }
    }
}
```

**EditSavePhotoFragment.java** [here i display the preview of image]

this is code to switch activity , when i called this my app crashes

```
 view.findViewById(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getActivity().onBackPressed();
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), BottomNavigationActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

below is full source code

```
public class EditSavePhotoFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = EditSavePhotoFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static String BITMAP_KEY = "bitmap_byte_array";
    public static String ROTATION_KEY = "rotation";
    public static String IMAGE_INFO = "image_info";


    private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String PHOTO_PREF = "PHOTO_PREF";
    private static final String CAPTURE_IMAGE_PATH = "CAPTURE_IMAGE_PATH";

    public static Fragment newInstance(byte[] bitmapByteArray, int rotation,
                                       @NonNull ImageParameters parameters) {
        Fragment fragment = new EditSavePhotoFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putByteArray(BITMAP_KEY, bitmapByteArray);
        args.putInt(ROTATION_KEY, rotation);
        args.putParcelable(IMAGE_INFO, parameters);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public EditSavePhotoFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.squarecamera__fragment_edit_save_photo, container, false);
        pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PHOTO_PREF, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();

        return  view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        int rotation = getArguments().getInt(ROTATION_KEY);
        byte[] data = getArguments().getByteArray(BITMAP_KEY);
        ImageParameters imageParameters = getArguments().getParcelable(IMAGE_INFO);

        if (imageParameters == null) {
            return;
        }

        final ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        imageParameters.mIsPortrait =
                getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

        final View topView = view.findViewById(R.id.topView);
        if (imageParameters.mIsPortrait) {
            topView.getLayoutParams().height = imageParameters.mCoverHeight;
        } else {
            topView.getLayoutParams().width = imageParameters.mCoverWidth;
        }

        rotatePicture(rotation, data, photoImageView);

        view.findViewById(R.id.save_photo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                savePicture(photoImageView);
            }
        });


        view.findViewById(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getActivity().onBackPressed();
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), BottomNavigationActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void rotatePicture(int rotation, byte[] data, ImageView photoImageView) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(getActivity(), data);
//        Log.d(TAG, "original bitmap width " + bitmap.getWidth() + " height " + bitmap.getHeight());
        if (rotation != 0) {
            Bitmap oldBitmap = bitmap;

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    oldBitmap, 0, 0, oldBitmap.getWidth(), oldBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false
            );

            oldBitmap.recycle();
        }

        photoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void savePicture(ImageView imageView)
    {
        /*
        try
        {
            SaveImageMethod(imageView);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */

        requestForPermission();
    }

    private void SaveImageMethod(ImageView iv) throws IOException
    {
        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SelfiLife");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
        File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

        Log.d("MainActivity","new IMAGE PATH  = "+outFile);
        editor.putString(CAPTURE_IMAGE_PATH, String.valueOf(outFile));
        editor.commit();

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }

    private void requestForPermission() {
        RuntimePermissionActivity.startActivity(EditSavePhotoFragment.this,
                REQUEST_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK != resultCode) return;

        if (REQUEST_STORAGE == requestCode && data != null) {
            final boolean isGranted = data.getBooleanExtra(RuntimePermissionActivity.REQUESTED_PERMISSION, false);
            final View view = getView();
            if (isGranted && view != null) {
                ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) photoImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Uri photoUri = ImageUtility.savePicture(getActivity(), bitmap);

                ((CameraActivity) getActivity()).returnPhotoUri(photoUri);
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182309/passing-bitmap-to-another-activity-ends-in-runtimeexception

Comment: can you call finish() after calling startActivity()? If it doens't work, please update the question with code for ImageCapture and ImagePreview

Comment: i called finish after startActivity() , not working..

Comment: `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2141164 byte` your extra size is 2mb and i think you can't pass more than 1 mb via extras. BTW what is your minimum sdk version?

Comment: @PriteshVishwakarma can you add the code for Image Preview? I am suspecting memory for Bitmap is got getting deallocated. You can try `bitmapObj.recycle()` to release the memory. But we can help only if you update the question with more information

Comment: @MuhammadBabar min sdk is 17

Comment: yes @Sagar i updated my question , now it contain my source code too of image capture and image preview display

Comment: Base on our code, you should get the error either on `args.putByteArray(BITMAP_KEY, bitmapByteArray);` in EditSavePhotoFragment or ` EditSavePhotoFragment.newInstance(data, rotation, mImageParameters.createCopy()),` 

The image captured from camera is more than 1 MB. which is causing the issue. On BackPress shouldn't be the issue.

You can use your `SaveImageMethod` and only pass the file path instead of `byte[]`. You can delete the file if user doesn't wish to save it.